# Enforcing the use of S/MIME for a specific sender and/or recipient domain in Outlook and/or Exchange

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013, outlook-2013

I want to ensure that Exchange 2013/Outlook 2013 only accepts messages originating from a specific sender domain if they were signed by S/MIME. All unsigned messages should not be delivered to the recipient but trigger an alarm (log messages, ...) or shall be redirected to an admin.

Further I would like to ensure that all messages sent to this domain (outbound) are also signed. The system should deny sending unsigned messages to this domain.

Is this possible in Exchange/Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain Exchange cannot do this out of the box. You need an Exchange addon or an external email encryption gateway to get this kind of functionality. I have done similar setups with an external email encryption gateway.

Comment: Since you've already done this, could you recommend a product?

Comment: If you look at my profile you will find a link to our website. Since the product we use was developed by us, we are by definition biased. There are other email encryption gateway products which might do a similar thing (although our product is afaik, the only open source email encryption gateway).